# Is there a way to make a name wrap when the information is coming from mysql on a php site?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I am building a large site. I decided to make it using a database. However, now that I am started, I am finding that the names of the pics are too large. Is there a way to make them wrap under the picture so they aren't so long? I am using PHPmyAdmin for the database and PHP in Dreamweaver CS5.5 for the coding.

Here is a picture to show you the current names.

[image: Here is a picture to show you the current names.]

I need it to do like this one.

[image: I need it to do like this one.]

Here is the current code:

```
  <?php do { ?>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="details.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_Master['Master_ID']; ?>"><img src="img/<?php 
echo $row_Master['Img']; ?>"/>
<br>
<?php echo $row_Master['Name']; ?></a></li>
  </ul>
  <?php } while ($row_Master = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Master)); ?>
  </div>
  <?php
mysqli_free_result($Master);
?>
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is *not* your database. MySQL is. phpMyAdmin is just a tool to make managing your database easier. That's a very basic fundamental distinction that you should know *before* you start working with databases.

Comment: Use CSS to specify the width of the DIV containing the name.

Comment: What does this have to do with namespaces?

Comment: This also has nothing to do with MySQL or PHP. HTML layout is independent of where the data came from or how the HTML was constructed.

Comment: @Barmar, this entire page is done using both PHP and MySQL, but I have found in other searches that if I don't include the phpMyAdmin part, it pull info for other types of datatbases that don't coordinate very well. As for Namespaces, the part I was trying to fix is actually a namespace.

Comment: The problem and solution are the same whether you're using PHP and MySQL, or just coding it as a static HTML page. PHP/MySQL are just a way to make the content dynamic, but the HTML and CSS rules are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your markup a bit. Add some class to `<ul>` element (like 'items' or as you wish) and put a name inside of `<span>` element:

```
<?php do { ?>
  <ul class="items">
    <li>
     <a href="details.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_Master['Master_ID']; ?>">
       <img src="img/<?php echo $row_Master['Img']; ?>"/>
       <span><?php echo $row_Master['Name']; ?></span>
     </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
<?php } while ($row_Master = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Master)); ?>
```

And add some styles:

```
<style>
    .items {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .items li {
        width: 100px; /* set your item width here */
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .items li a {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .items li a img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .items li a span {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

Here is a result example for you:

```css
.div {
  width: 600px;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}
.items li {
  width: 100px; /* set your item width here */
  margin: 10px;
}
.items li a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.items li a img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.items li a span {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <ul class="items">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
        <span>title example</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
        <span>the photo large title example</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
        <span>the photo large title example</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
        <span>the photo large title example</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
        <span>the photo large title example</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
        <span>the photo large title example</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This one kind of helped. But I didn't use the span. I just adjusted the max-width on the display ul li. That fixed the text issue.